# Formatting Strings to fit a box shape in the output console

Tags: java, string

So I am trying to fit a String called description into a box. For example:

```
|This is the description   |
|of this card. It is very  |
|interesting               |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
```

My code does exactly this. However I am afraid I am being very inefficient.

So my question, Is my approach and code effective? or is there any other more convenient way WITHOUT USING LIBRARIES of approaching and coding this problem? I am NOT asking you to re-write my code for me. All I need is someone to verbally explain to me what I could improve on, How I'm approaching the problem incorrectly, what resources I can use to help me etc.

My approach:

1. Put all the words from the string into an array.
2. Create an array to contain all the rows that I need to print out.
3. Insert the words into the rows if they can fit, if not then move onto the next row.

NOTE: If the description is too long then it gets cut short which I don't mind.

So this is my code (I realise that it is very bulky, that is why I feel there is a better way of doing this):

```
public String[] descriptionFormat(String description)
    {
        int wordCount = 1; //Int for keeping track words amount in String
        for(int i = 0; i < description.length(); i++) //Count the amount of words in the String
        {
            if(description.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                wordCount++;
            }
        }
        
        String words[] = new String[wordCount]; //Array of words
        String temp = description;
        for(int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) //loop for filling array with words
        {
            String word = "";
            if(temp.indexOf(' ') != -1)
            {
                word = temp.substring(0,temp.indexOf(' '));
                temp = temp.substring(temp.indexOf(' ') + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                word = temp.substring(0,temp.length());
            }
            words[i] = word;
        }

        String descriptionArray[] = new String[7]; //Array of description rows
        for(int i = 0; i < descriptionArray.length; i++) //Fill array with non null values
        {
            descriptionArray[i] = "";
        }
        
        int word = 0; //int to keep track which word we trying to insert
        for(int i = 0; i < descriptionArray.length; i++)
        {
            int index = 0; //index for how much characters we already have in a row
            
            while(word < words.length && words[word].length() < (rowWidth - 3) - index ) //while the word can fit into the row
            {
                index += words[word].length() + 1;
                descriptionArray[i] += words[word] + " ";
                word++;
            }
            
        }
        
        for(int i = 0; i < descriptionArray.length; i++)
        {
            descriptionArray[i] = "|" + descriptionArray[i]; //add left border
            while(descriptionArray[i].length() < rowWidth - 2) //insert appropriate spaces
            {
                descriptionArray[i] += " "; 
            }
            descriptionArray[i] = descriptionArray[i] + "|"; //add right border
        }
        /*
        for(int i = 0; i < descriptionArray.length; i++) //print rows for test
        {
            System.out.println(descriptionArray[i]);
        }
        */
        return descriptionArray;
    }
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  Good question, wrong site.

Comment: Wouldn't description.split(" ") help simplify the code?

Answer (score 1):

With regex and `printf()`, it can be done like this:

```java
static void printColumn(String input, int width) {
    String format = "|%-" + width + "s|%n";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s*+(.{1," + width + "})(?:\\s+|$)").matcher(input);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.printf(format, m.group(1));
}
```

*Test 1*

```java
printColumn("This is the description of this card. It is very interesting", 26);
```

```
|This is the description of|
|this card. It is very     |
|interesting               |
```

*Test 2*

```java
printColumn("This is the description of this card.\n" +
            "It is very interesting", 26);
```

```
|This is the description of|
|this card.                |
|It is very interesting    |
```